# joint between multitable in linq c# return unexpected rows

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query :

```
from m in _ctx.MaterialRequestContractorDetails
where m.MaterialRequestContractorId == MRCId
join mat in _ctx.MaterialDescriptions on m.MaterialDescriptionId equals mat.Id
join l in _ctx.Lines on m.LineId equals l.Id 
join sheet in _ctx.Sheets on m.SheetId equals sheet.Id
join joint in _ctx.Joints on m.SheetId equals joint.SheetId 
join testjoint in _ctx.TestPackageJoints on joint.Id equals testjoint.Id
join testpack in _ctx.TestPackages on testjoint.TestPackageId equals testpack.Id
```

I have connection between:

- `MaterialRequestContractorDetails` and `sheet`
- `MaterialRequestContractorDetails` and `line`

but I don't have any connection between `MaterialRequestContractorDetails` and `testpackage`.

I can have a connection with `testpackage` using  `joint` and `testpackagejoint`, but this connection makes a problem and my records repeat with similar data based on `joint` row

I mean if I have 2 records in my joint table, my result repeats 2 times with similar data.

Comment: It's normal, this is how joins (and SQL joins for many years) work. The question is though what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @IvanStoev so you mean i can't have just one result ?

Comment: but when i call my function in ui :            List<ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor> lstMaterialRequestContractorDetails = _reportMaterialRequestContractorRepository.ShowReport(Id).Distinct().ToList(); the result changed to two similar records.i have 2 records in sheet table

Comment: All I'm saying that when you join `one` table with `many` table, you get many records. Again, we can help if you show **why** do you need that join.

Comment: @IvanStoev i need the packagenumber that is in the testpackage table

Comment: Ok, the question then is how you can get **one** packagenumber when you have **many** joints?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes exactly

Comment: What kind of LINQ are you using (to entities?). And where are the navigation properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is a `GroupJoin` function. In a query syntax it will look like this:

```
var result = (from m in MaterialRequestContractorDetails
              where m.MaterialRequestContractorId == MRCId

              join mat in MaterialDescriptions on m.MaterialDescriptionId equals mat.Id
              join l in Lines on m.LineId equals l.Id
              join sheet in Sheets on m.SheetId equals sheet.Id

              join joint in (from joint in Joints
                             join testjoint in TestPackageJoints on joint.Id equals testjoint.Id
                             join testpack in TestPackages on testjoint.TestPackageId equals testpack.Id
                             select new { joint.SheetId, testpack })

              on m.SheetId equals joint.SheetId into tt

              select new { Details = m, Line = l, TestPacks = tt.Select(x => x.testpack).ToList() }).ToList();
```

What I actually did is separate all the "second half" of the joins into a nested select and then joined it with the main part, but when doing so used the `into` keyword (`GroupJoin`).

With the testing data bellow I got 1 record with the `MRCId` of 1 and in the record had a list of `TestPackage` containing 2 items.

```
List<dynamic> MaterialRequestContractorDetails = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { MaterialRequestContractorId = 1, MaterialDescriptionId = 1, LineId = 1, SheetId = 1},
    new { MaterialRequestContractorId = 2, MaterialDescriptionId = 2, LineId = 2, SheetId = 2},
};

List<dynamic> MaterialDescriptions = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Id = 1 }, new { Id = 2 },
};

List<dynamic> Lines = new List<dynamic> { new { Id = 1 } };
List<dynamic> Sheets = new List<dynamic> { new { Id = 1 } };
List<dynamic> Joints = new List<dynamic> { new { SheetId  = 1, Id = 1 } };

List<dynamic> TestPackageJoints = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Id = 1, TestPackageId = 1 },
    new { Id = 1, TestPackageId = 2 },
};

List<dynamic> TestPackages = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Id = 1 }, new { Id = 2 },
};

int MRCId = 1;
```

Comment: Hi .could you please take a look  at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243771/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-view

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - will check :)