# Efficiently convert rows to columns in SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, join, view, group-by

I have 3 tables: `testpackage`, `testpackageReport`, `testpackagereportdetail` with this structure:

[image]

With this query

```
SELECT        
    dbo.TestPackages.PackageNumber, dbo.TestPackages.Size, 
    dbo.TestPackages.Code, dbo.TestPackageReports.ReportNumber,   
    dbo.TestPackageReportDetails.Step, dbo.TestPackageReportDetails.Status, 
    dbo.TestPackageReports.SubmitDateTime, 
    dbo.TestPackageReportDetails.Id AS ReportDetailId
FROM
    dbo.TestPackages 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TestPackageReportDetails ON dbo.TestPackages.Id = dbo.TestPackageReportDetails.TestPackageId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TestPackageReports ON dbo.TestPackageReportDetails.TestPackageReportId = dbo.TestPackageReports.Id
```

The result is this:

```
PackageNumber   Size    Code    ReportNumber    Step        Status  SubmitDateTime  ReportDetailId
1000220-G-02-TR 1.31    143     LC-0431         LineCheck   Reject  2010-12-12     218
1000220-G-02-TR 1.31    143     LC-0131         LineCheck   Accept  2011-12-12     220
1000220-G-02-TR 1.31    143     PT-0248         Test        Accept  2012-12-12     513
1000220-G-02-TR 1.31    143     DR-0202         Drying      Accept  2013-12-12     625
1000220-G-02-TR 1.31    143     AFP-AG-FL-0030  Flushing    Accept  2015-12-12     745
```

But I need to show this data just in one row like this:

```
 PackageNumber   Size   Code    LineCheckReportNumber   LineCheckStep       LineCheckStatus linecheckSubmitDateTime ReportDetailId      tesReportNumber testCheckStep       testStatus  testSubmitDateTime  ReportDetailId

1000220-G-02-TR 1.31   143             LC-0431          LineCheck                Accept       2011-12-12              220                      PT-0248        Test               Accept       2012-12-12              513
```

For noisy data in the expected result I remove drying and flushing columns. As you can see I need all this records to be shown as a one row, another this that is important is the data with maximum `ReportDetailId` that is `accepted` because every `testpackage` can have multi `linecheck` or `test` or `flsuhing` or `drying` reports

Sample data:

**TestpackageTable**

[image]

**TestpackageReport**

[image]

**Testpackagereportdetail**

[image]

I write the query using entity framework as you can see but it is very slow :

```
from i in _ctx.TestPackages
join testpackreportdet in _ctx.TestPackageReportDetails on i.Id equals
    testpackreportdet.TestPackageId
join testPackageRepo in _ctx.TestPackageReports on testpackreportdet.TestPackageReportId equals testPackageRepo.Id into g1
from y1 in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
group new { y1, testpackreportdet } by new { i }
into grouping
let MaxLinecheck = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
    .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "LineCheck")
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxClean = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
    .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "Clean")
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxTest = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
    .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "Test")
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxFlush = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
    .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "Flushing")
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxDrying = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
    .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "Drying")
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxReins = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
    .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "Reinstatment")
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxMono = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
 .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "Mono")
 .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxPAD = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
 .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "PADTest")
 .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

let MaxVariation = grouping.Select(item => item.testpackreportdet)
 .Where(item => item != null && item.Step == "Variation")
 .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)
    select new ViewDomainClass.TechnicalOffice.ViewTestPackageState()
    {
        Id = grouping.Key.i.Id,
        PackageNumber = grouping.Key.i.PackageNumber,
        Size = grouping.Key.i.Size.ToString(),
        Code = grouping.Key.i.Code,
        TestPackageOrder = grouping.Key.i.TestPackageOrder,
        LineCheckState = MaxLinecheck.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        LineCheckSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(
                i => i.y1.Id == MaxLinecheck.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        LineCheckReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(
                i => i.y1.Id == MaxLinecheck.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,
        CleaningState = MaxClean.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        CleanSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxClean.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        CleanReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxClean.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,
        TestState = MaxTest.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        TestSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxTest.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        TestReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxTest.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,

        Drying = MaxDrying.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        DryingSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxDrying.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        DryingReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxDrying.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,
        Flushing = MaxFlush.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        FlushingSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxFlush.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        FlushingReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxFlush.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,
        ReInstatement = MaxReins.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        ReInstatementSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxReins.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        ReInstatementReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxReins.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,
        Mono = MaxMono.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        MonoSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxMono.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        MonoReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxMono.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,
        Variation = MaxVariation.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        VariationSubmitDateTime =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxVariation.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        VariationReportNumber =
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxVariation.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber,
        PAD = MaxPAD.FirstOrDefault().Status,
        PADSubmitDateTime = 
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxPAD.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.SubmitDateTime.ToString(),
        PADReportNumber = 
            grouping.Where(i => i.y1.Id == MaxPAD.FirstOrDefault().TestPackageReportId)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .y1.ReportNumber
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you trying to show all the data like the sample from table?

Comment: @AT-2016 I want to show all data just in one record.

Comment: @AT-2016 my sample data is just for one testpackage ,maybe there are more than one testpackage in my data

Comment: You can use pivot for this. This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: @AT-2016 thank you but in fact i can't how can i use it in my query because my query result should be the maximum with accept state

Comment: I can understand it's a bit tricky. Try to implement it in a small range of data with a sample query and finally in your query.

Comment: Yes let me do that

Comment: @GiladGreen i added to my post

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - can you post the data in the seperate tables that gave you the result for that sql? will be easier to understand the connections that way

Comment: In fact in each table i have lots of data , i can't do this :(

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - use `where`s - I can't currently understand what to group,select,join...

Comment: @GiladGreen Would you like to give you teamviewer to check my problem directly?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - I prefer not... SO questions should be in such a way that all is needed is posted in the question..

Comment: @GiladGreen i will post the data just for one package to see .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pivoting and dynamic SQL. I would suggest to put output of your query into temporary table and then work with it:

```
USE YourDatabase --Use your database

SELECT  TP.PackageNumber,
        TP.Size, 
        TP.Code, 
        R.ReportNumber,   
        RD.Step, 
        RD.[Status], 
        R.SubmitDateTime, 
        RD.Id AS ReportDetailId
INTO #temporary --it will automatically create #temporary table with results
FROM dbo.TestPackages TP
INNER JOIN dbo.TestPackageReportDetails RD
    ON TP.Id = RD.TestPackageId 
INNER JOIN dbo.TestPackageReports R
    ON RD.TestPackageReportId = R.Id

USE tempdb --switch to tempdb

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * INTO #temp
FROM #temporary
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PackageNumber, Size, Code, Step ORDER BY ReportDetailId DESC) 
--Here we get only rows with maximum ReportDetailID over PackageNumber, Size, Code, Step

DROP TABLE #temporary --get rid of #temporary, now we use #temp

DECLARE @pvt_columns nvarchar(max), --to store columns for pivoting
        @unpvt_columns nvarchar(max), --to store columns that will be converted into 1 datatype for unpivoting
        @columns nvarchar(max), -- columns comma separated
        @sql nvarchar(max) --store query to run

SELECT @pvt_columns = COALESCE(@pvt_columns,'') + ','+QUOTENAME(Step+name)
FROM (
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'#temp')
    AND name not in ('PackageNumber','Size','Code','Step')
) names
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Step
    FROM #temp
    ) steps


SELECT  @unpvt_columns = COALESCE(@unpvt_columns,'')+',CAST('+QUOTENAME(name)+' as nvarchar(max)) '+QUOTENAME(name),
        @columns = COALESCE(@columns,'') + ','+QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'#temp')
AND name not in ('PackageNumber','Size','Code','Step')

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  PackageNumber,
            Size,
            Code,
            Step+[Columns] as [Columns],
            [Values]
    FROM (
        SELECT  PackageNumber,
                Size,
                Code,
                Step'+@unpvt_columns+'
        FROM #temp) t
    UNPIVOT (
        [Values] FOR [Columns] IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
    ) unpvt
    ) p
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR [Columns] in ('+STUFF(@pvt_columns,1,1,'')+')
) pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Output:

```
PackageNumber   Size    Code    DryingReportDetailId    DryingReportNumber  DryingStatus    DryingSubmitDateTime    FlushingReportDetailId  FlushingReportNumber    FlushingStatus  FlushingSubmitDateTime  LineCheckReportDetailId LineCheckReportNumber   LineCheckStatus LineCheckSubmitDateTime TestReportDetailId  TestReportNumber    TestStatus  TestSubmitDateTime
1000220-G-02-TR 1,31    143     625                     DR-0202             Accept          2013-12-12              745                     AFP-AG-FL-0030          Accept          2015-12-12              220                     LC-0131                 Accept          2011-12-12              513                 PT-0248             Accept      2012-12-12
```

You can `SELECT` variables to see what is stored in them, and `PRINT @sql` to see the full text of query.

Comment: It is great! My pleasure! :)

Comment: Hi the man power of SQL server.So sorry for my problems .could you please give me some help for this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269277/read-data-from-another-columns-to-current-table-in-sql