# Read data from another columns to current table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileISOManagers]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LineId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Revision] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubmitDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lines]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LineNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DocumentNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Revision] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

Every line has multiple revisions, so I just need to insert the last `revision` column value in `FileISOManagers` table inside `Revision` column in `lines`  table automatically. I want do this in SQL Server. Is there any solution to do this? Should I use a trigger?

[image]

revision

[image]

Comment: When you change the isofile revision you should update other column too.

Comment: @NEER yes exactly , i mean after update delete and insert

Comment: Please, elaborate, in what table you will INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE data? and where you want to store LAST revision?

Comment: In line i want to store last update of revision and in isofile i insert update and delete

Comment: @gofr1 in fact every changes in isofile should be applied on line \

Comment: And what is `LineNumber` and `DocumentNumber` columns? How they correspondent with `FileISOManagers`?

Comment: They are columns and they don't correspond to iso file

Comment: Well, what will be stored in this columns?

Comment: @gofr1 You mean the type of them ?it's just a number

Comment: No, bring the example please, I add a column in `FileISOManagers` like `(1,1,'Revision 01','example.txt',123,'2016-09-01 10:00:00.000')` what will be passed to `Lines`?

Comment: I added to my post dear

Comment: One more time :) I give you sample that will be inserted in your table, what should go to `Lines` table? How we can help if we don't know what data from target table should be inserted?

Comment: @goft the line table data is static and never changed

Comment: (facepalm) I don't understand. Where will you insert data, and where last revision should be stored.

Comment: @gofr1 I insert data into isofile table just it .

Comment: And why you add `lines` to question? :)

Comment: @gofr1 because the revision  column in line table should be updated based on the last revision in iso file

Comment: OK, what data will be inserted/updated  in `Lines` when new `Revision` come in `FileISOManagers`? Please, show what data is in `FileISOManagers` and what should be in `Lines`

Comment: @gofr1 yes ,i added to the post .Let me explain in detail.When every changes occurred in revision columns in isofile table it should be applied on revision column in line table .i mean the last item revision value should be inserted in line column

Comment: and older values from `lines` must be deleted?

Comment: @gofr1 for example if there is no record in isofile table with specific line id the revision column value of line should be '' ,if isofile is added the value of this data should be placed in line revision column ,it it updated it should be updated in line again and if deleted .it should return the last value that is stored in isofile table

Comment: @gofr1 suppose there are more than one values isofile for specific line in isofile table if the value is deleted the latest value should be replaced

Comment: Dont know why you need this `Lines` table, you can use view based on `FileISOManagers` that will select only last rows based on datetime column and some partition like `LineNum`

Comment: @gofr1 yes you are right ,but in fact  i have to do this ,i don't have more choices

Comment: @gofr1 you know the problem is i have a lot of queries and this changes can effect on them

Comment: @gofr1 can i have you in chat ?how can i do that?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122425/sql-aaa

Answer (score 1):

```
 -- Create trigger on table FileISOManagers for Insert statement
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert on FileISOManagers
FOR INSERT
AS declare @Revision varchar(100);
select @Revision=i.Revision from inserted i;
set @action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.'; insert into Lines(Revision)
values (@Revision);
PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.
```

Comment: It shouldn't insert in the line it should update the line column

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using joins and alias.

#### Example

```
INSERT INTO FileISOManagers (Revision ..columns)
 SELECT *
  FROM Lines ls
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM FileISOManagers
   WHERE LineId = ls.id       
) order by ls.id desc
```

Comment: I want to do this automatically i mean if i change the isofile revision my changes applied to line revision column

Comment: I don't want to use join

Comment: Ok..then you can use trigger